# Extrude precision

Tags: modeling, normals

I'm trying to extrude faces in a precise amount, I tried doing so using Extrude -> Right click, and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and hitting 0.3 (for 30 cm), the offset number seems right, but the amount of extrusion is definitely not, I used the Ruler to measure it and it was 51 cm, am I doing something wrong here?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

OK, I guess I found the answer, I needed to freeze the object scale using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> before applying the Extrude